# Trying to access public objects in other package

Tags: java, object, package

Hi I am trying to access a public object in another package within a project.

I am trying to access the 'opponent' object which is of type 'Character' in the Attribute class.

```
public class Engine {
    public static Character opponent;
}
```

Class I am trying to access object in.  "This class is in another package".

```
public int opponentAttackDamage() {     
    int attack = opponent.getAttribute().getAttack();
}
```

Comment: In your question it appears as though opponent is contained within the Engine class and not the Attribute class

Comment: you are correct opponent is a static variable in the engine class.  I believed it to be possible to still access that same object because its declared static from another class.

Comment: So where is the `opponentAttackDamage()` method defined?

Comment: in Attribute class, which is in another package.

Comment: So to be clear, you want the Engine class to be able to call a method in the Attribute class through the Character class?

Comment: I figured it out.  i needed to extend the Engine class.

Answer (score 3):

In order to access an static attribute from anywhere even in the same class where it's declared (as a good practice) you should use the name of the class follow by dot an the name of the attribute:

```
Engine.opponent.getAttribute().getAttack();
```

Also you should have in mind that opponent object must be initialized in somewhere in your class (opponent = new Opponent() - I guess - ).

Answer (score 0):

If opponent is a static attribute of the Engine class, and the method you are accessing it from is not in the same class, you need to mention Engine.opponent to access it. Also, you need to import the package where Engine class is defined.